# Complete http request before loading template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My template loads first then http request is fired because of which when I load page first time it shows 404 image src not found in console but then after micro-seconds loads data successfully. After googling a bit I found that we can handle this situation using resolve property.Below is my implementation of resolve.

```
var app=angular.module('websiteApp',['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$httpProvider){
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/movies");
$stateProvider.state('movies',
    {
        url:"/movies",
        templateUrl:"views/movies.html",
        controller:"moviesController",
        resolve:
        {
         movieslist:moviesController.getallMovies
        }
    })});
```

My Controller :

```
var moviesController=app.controller('moviesController',
function($scope,movieslist){
$scope.movies=movieslist.data.result
});

moviesController.getallMovies=function($q,$timeout,movieservice)
{
var defer=$q.defer();
$timeout(function(){
    defer.resolve(movieservice.getlist());
},1000);
return defer.promise;
}
```

My Service :

```
app.factory('movieservice',function($http,$location){
var movieserviceObj={};
movieserviceObj.getlist=function(){
dataString={mode:'list',page:1,recordsperpage:10};
return $http({ url:'app/api/entertainment.php',data:$.param(dataString),method:'POST'});
};
return movieserviceObj;
```

});

My Template [Sample] :

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" ng-repeat="movie in movies"> 
<img src='public/images/{{movie.image}}' style="width: 175px;"/> 
</div>
```

But still my movies.html loads before my http request(1 sec delay) so my console error is still not disappeared.Is this the correct way to implement resolve in angularjs.

Comment: Have you tried `ng-src`?

Comment: @davin Hey thanks,ng-src solved my issue.Wasted my 1hr for this.

Comment: @davin In above example if http call is completed before 1 sec[which it does]. How can return promise immediately instead of using timeout.

Answer (score 2):

From Angular documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc):

### ngSrc - directive in module ng

Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.

The buggy way to write it:

```
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}"/>
```

The correct way to write it:

```
<img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}"/>
```